# List domain users with wmi

Tags: windows, dns, c#, wmi

I want to list all users of a Windows domain with WMI in C#.

Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
try
            {
                ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
                connection.Username = user;
                connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + domain;
                connection.Password = pwd;

                SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount");
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\FullComputerName\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
                scope.Connect();
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Account Type: " + queryObj["AccountType"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Caption: " + queryObj["Caption"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Description: " + queryObj["Description"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Disabled: " + queryObj["Disabled"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + queryObj["Domain"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Full Name: " + queryObj["FullName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Local Account: " + queryObj["LocalAccount"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Lockout: " + queryObj["Lockout"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + queryObj["Name"].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Changeable: " + queryObj["PasswordChangeable"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Expires: " + queryObj["PasswordExpires"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Required: " + queryObj["PasswordRequired"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("SID: " + queryObj["SID"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("SID Type: " + queryObj["SIDType"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + queryObj["Status"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured while querying for WMI data: " + err.Message);
            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedErr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection error " + "(user name or password might be incorrect): " + unauthorizedErr.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Why C? Powershell should have little trouble doing this...

Comment: Ok, so what happens when you run this?  Like, what doesn't work about it?  What have you tried already to trace/rectify the problem?

Comment: If I run this it say its a wrong parameter

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the namespace path in your `ManagementScope` constructor:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\FullComputerName\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
```

The string should be either `@"\\FullComputerName\root\CIMV2"` or `"\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\CIMV2"`.

Note that you cannot specify the user account for local connections. So if `FullComputerName` is a local computer, use this instead:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
```